# Save Canvas to PNG for iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, canvas, html5-canvas

I use react and html-to-image to export HTML to images. Because Safari not working properly with the jpg/png export, I need to export HTML node to SVG (data url is generated like this : data:image/svg...).

With this string, I am creating a new Image inside a Canvas then saving canvas to .Png with method canvas.toDataURL("image/png").

Everything is working on Firefox/Chrome, but on Safari, it's not working the first time.

- First Click - Just avec HTML node (no text)
- Second Click - Some Images + Previous HTML Node
- Third Click - Everything is working

[image]

Here is part of my function :

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  var img = new Image; 

  setTimeout(()=>{
    htmlToImage.toSvg(document.querySelector('.Banner'), {pixelRatio: RatioVal}).then((dataUrl) => {            
      canvas.width = 1300*RatioVal;
      canvas.height = 690*RatioVal;            
      img.src = dataUrl;     

      img.onload = () => {        
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height)  
        var Export = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");   
        document.body.append(Export)
        var a = document.createElement('a');       
        a.href = Export;
        a.download = window.Chara.Nom+".png";
        a.click();              
      };                  
    })
  },600)
```

Do you know why I need to click on Export 3 times to have a full image ?
Is this the best way to convert SVG dataUrl to PNG Image ?

I tried many things (Blob to Png etc..) but the problem is the same on Safari.

Comment: have you tried adding your anchor element to the DOM tree? Maybe Safari prevents downloading things from links that are not on the page for some security reasons?
Try doing: `a.style.display = "none"; document.body.appendChild(a);` just before `a.click();`

Comment: @TimNimets Did it, but the problem is still here :/ Need to download Three times